# How do I setup a filehosting site

Tags: web-hosting

I want to start a filehosting and filesharing website like rapidshare.com / mediafire.com. I'm thinking of using [hostmonster](http://hostmonster.com) as my webhost, as they are offering unlimited hosting space and bandwidth. What things I'll have to be concerned with? Any further suggestsions

**EDIT:**

Just found that, hostmonster doesn't allow such services. What are the alternatives then?

Comment: Read the terms (http://www.hostmonster.com/cgi/info/terms.html) carefully:  "Please note, however, that the Hostmonster service is designed to host websites. Hostmonster does NOT provide unlimited space for online storage, backups, or archiving of electronic files..."

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anything below a dedicated server (or a powerful virtual one) will do. And they do not come cheap. You could also host your own server, but there, again, you will need a fast internet connection (like fibre optic) and backups and redundancy and the like.

Note that you will not only require a server, but also support or a tech team to solve performance issues.

These are all things that you do not get with cheap shared hosting. I suggest you do more research on this matter. But my bet is that unless you invest some serious money, you do not get to host your own file sharing service.

**Edit:**
If you are serious about Filehosting, you might want to look for filehosters that offer some kind of reselling program with branding (i.e. you can use your own label). A list of Filehosts can be found here: http://premium-account.org/en/1-home.

I was not able to find such an offer quickly, though.

Comment: Agree, the fact that OP needs to ask this question gives away that they are not up to creating a full blown file-sharing service like RapidShare/Mediafire (who manage petabtyes of data)

Comment: @Dunhamzzz "...gives away that they are not up to creating a full blown file-sharing..." I'd be careful with this kind of normative statement. This site is to help people, not to judge them.

Comment: Well it was helpful in telling OP you should be way past this level (especially with hosting) before trying to create the next RapidShare.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an API to store the actual data on AmazonS3, for example. All you need to host web-wise is the interface, which could be very light. Keep the two parts as separate entities. I don't know of a better service than Amazon S3 for that kind of massive storage ability.